# Webgl canvas appears semi transparent over another canvas

Tags: html5-canvas, webgl

I am trying to implement webgl for my game. The problem is I use multiple canvases, and my webgl enabled canvas is semi-transparent over my terrain canvas (which is drawn once and just moves with the player). Here is a picture:

[image]

I've searched for the past 2 hours on google and can't find anything that has helped.

I have tried:

```
getContext("experimental-webgl",{alpha: false});
```

This just hides the terrain completely (now all black), but my webgl drawn objects have the correct color.

```
gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_PREMULTIPLY_ALPHA_WEBGL, false);

gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_COLORSPACE_CONVERSION_WEBGL, false);
```

Neither of these did anything noticeable.

```
gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Didn't affect the outcome, still looks like the screenshot above.

Everything else here: http://games.greggman.com/game/webgl-and-alpha/

Nothing seems to work. Why is what is drawn on the canvas semi transparent? There is no CSS affecting the canvas element.

Comment: Unfortunately, it drew in transparent red.  http://imgur.com/MKGXJHl.png

Comment: Without code we can just guess, and the link you posted is to a tutorial you might have followed incorrectly. Please create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). You will likely find your solution that way yourself, so when you don't reply I will assume that you successful found the problem while creating one.

Comment: Can you link to the image somewhere? Are you sure the source image doesn't have alpha? What's your shader look like? Try adding `gl_FragColor.a = 1.0;` to the end of your shader.

Comment: Figured it out!  I am using WebGL-2D, which is a javascript file that adds the context2D API to webGL.  So if I call drawImage, it actually handles that with webgl.  In the getContext definition I had to change:

gl.colorMask(1,1,1,0);

to

gl.colorMask(1,1,1,1);

The colorMask() method specifies whether red, green, blue, and alpha can or cannot be written into the frame buffer.

I have no idea why it was 0 before.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!  I am using WebGL-2D, which is a javascript file that adds the context2D API to webGL.  So if I call drawImage, it actually handles that with webgl.  In the getContext definition I had to change:

gl.colorMask(1,1,1,0);

to

gl.colorMask(1,1,1,1);

The colorMask() method specifies whether red, green, blue, and alpha can or cannot be written into the frame buffer.

I have no idea why it was 0 before.